# Password encryption with passport.js

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, passwords, passport.js

I'm building a single page app with express.js as backend. Currently I'm using passport.js local strategy for authentication, saving on db the encrypted password with bcrypt. During authentication, the password provided by the user is encrypted again and confronted with the one stored on db. However I'm currently sending the password to the server as clear text, and I'm understanding this is a really bad and unsecure practice. To do this correctly I'm understanding I have to:

- create random bytes on the server and send them to the client
- create random bytes on the client
- concatenate the encrypted password and the the two set of bytes and encrypt all of them
- send back to the server the encrypted object and the bytes generated on the client as clear text
- reproduce the same encrypted object on the server and check for a valid authentication

I could do this again with bcrypt and some random generator on the client, but I have the strong feeling I should NOT implement this on my own. There's some integration with passport or some node library I'm not aware of?

Comment: That's not going to work.  You absolutely, positively need TLS (SSL) to protect communications from server to client.  There are more secure options, but they are a lot of work.  In the short term the best thing you can do is turn TLS on and not fiddle with anything crazy like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTTPS (SSL) to encrypt the communication between server-client

Comment: is this enough for secure web app ?

Comment: This solves the problem of the password being clear text in transit but it doesn't solve the problem of the server knowing the password in clear text, being able to write it to logs, etc. Almost nobody does it, but it is best practice to hash the password on the client, send that hash, and then re-hash it on the server.